# Write phone number without call

Tags: android, delphi, call, firemonkey

I'm using IFMXPhoneDialerService to make a call with Firemonkey on mobile.

I ask for CALL_PHONE permission and do :

```
PhoneDialerService.Call(aNumero)
```

That's works fine but i didn't want the phone start the call, only write the number to call and let the user to click on call button.

It's a list of emergency number, so I prefer. There isn't overload method Call with parameter to do it. Maybe I should use something else, but I don't know what ?

Exemple of the call : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_the_Phone_Dialer_on_Mobile_Devices_(iOS_and_Android)

Comment: Is this really android? Or some other OS? If it's android you can just use `Intent`s

Comment: Android and iOS :)